# Path not found when executing my python script from my cmd prompt

Tags: python, path

[image: folders]

I have a python script that uses classes from a file next to my main.py named 'src'. These classes use images from the file 'img' next to main.py as well.

I'm writting the path as follows :

"img/myImage.gif"

When I run it from my python shell it works fine but I just can't run it using the command prompt (path not found).

I tried

"/img/myImage.gif" and "./img/myImage.gif"

and also moving my 'img' file to src, and to main.py's parent file but it doesn't work..

I'm out of ideas.. any assistance would be appreciated, Thanks,

Comment: is your current working directory inside your python paths? also you'd better share your code for more clarification.

Comment: please share directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do for you folder structure,

```
program
   main.py
   src
      __init__.py //empty py file
      classA
           __init__.py
           classA.py

      classB
           __init__.py
           classB.py

"../../img/myimage.gif"          // to use in classA.py file
```

More Explanation:

if your main.py is in

```
    src
       main.py
    img
       myimage.gif
```

use this

```
"../img/myimage.gif"
```

if your folder structure is (moving img inside src)

```
-src
    main.py
   -img
       myimage.gif
```

you need to use like below

```
"img/myimage.gif"
```

Comment: thanks for this clarification, I think that I also have to add the path of my project to the PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: wel, i think so we should. main.py and classA.py are not in same level, and Python cant able to figure out if main.py importing classA.py module!! let me know if i m wrong. do accept this ans if this resolved your problem :)

Comment: try doing this in main.py, import os, sys

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

sys.path.append(PROJECT_PATH)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'classA'))

Comment: my classes are found because they are imported in my main as follows:

from src.classA.ClassA import ClassA

but within these classes I can't load my images (from 'img')

Comment: I tried to add all this in main.py (changing 'file' with the path of my project and changing 'classA' to 'img') but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: you have two options,1. in classA module refer "myimage" with absolute path. 2. under folder "src" create (__init__.py) and under classA and classB folder create "__init__.py" (this might solve ur problem) not able mention "_" underscore inthe comment ( underscore-underscore-init-underscore-underscore-.py)

Comment: I do have __init__.py within every folders

Comment: create file (init empty file)  reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: It seems to work with absolute paths but I'd like to avoid it if possible

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the user's current directory, not your script's (though there are ways to achieve the latter, too).